# CDialogEx constructor and inherited Create() method

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

When i programatically create a non-modal dialog from a dialog resource ID i use the following code:

```
CDialogEx myDialog(IDD_DIALOG1, this);
...
myDialog.Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this);
```

One can see that this isn't very practical as one needs to pass the dialog ID twice. 
Did i understand something wrong about the creation of a dialog?
Is there a way to avoid that repetition?

What is the reason that the MFC class `CDialogEx` provides a constructor

```
CDialogEx(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent=NULL);
```

but also an inherited method

```
virtual BOOL CDialog::Create(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL);
```

which forces me to repeat the dialog ID?

The reason behind is that i want to derive an own class `myDialogClass` from `CDialogEx` but do not want to assign an ID at this point. Would it be possibly ok to pass a dummy ID to the `CDialogEx` constructor?
I want to assign the ID when i create the dialog window, not before.

```
class MyDialogClass: public CDialogEx{
    ...
    public:
    MyDialogClass(CWnd* pParent=NULL):CDialogEx(DUMMY_ID, pParent){}
}
```

Furthermore i want to extract my dialog class into an own library (MFC extension library) and use it in some other code.
My dialog class provides an additional memory DC to the normal DC, but this could just be any other functionality.
I want to use this additional functionality in several contexts.

Comment: It depends on how you want the dialog: modal or not. `Create` is used for modeless dialogs.

Comment: I want to create a modeless dialog. This is indeed the case. I've updated the question to make this more clear. My dialog should provide additional functionality (in this case a memory DC), but the exact functionality doesn't matter, here. And i want to put it into an external class library.

Comment: `CDialog` has a default constructor. I do not know about `CDialogEx` and I am not near a computer to check it. [These](http://www.flounder.com/kb103788.htm) guidelines might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*“Did i understand something wrong about the creation of a dialog?”* There are two scenarios a dialog box may be used: modal & modeless. You **mixed** them:

[image: afxwin.h]

`CDialog` & **`CDialogEx` provides a parameterless constructor** which may be used with the modeless scenario. Your code becomes:

```
CDialogEx myDialog();
// ...
myDialog.Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this);
```

For more information on how to correctly implement a modeless dialog, see **[this](http://www.flounder.com/kb103788.htm)**.

Comment: Thank you for the info. For some reason i was convinced there was no parameterless constructor.

Comment: @noop It happens.

Comment: "The parameterless constructor is protected and can be used only in derived classes", according to the MS docs. However, that's exactly what i want to do. But maybe that's the reason i've overseen this.

Comment: MS docs provide correct information to some degree. They are not always in sync with the actual code. The constructor is currently public. See the image above or afxwin.h & afxdialogex.h files on your computer.